# Find duplicate rows but only for a unique column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Using Oracle 12c. I am trying to identify duplicate rows that have a unique *ref1_descr* field. The count should be grouped on the first 3 columns (*emplid*, *item_type* and *acad_year*) and it should only count *ref1_descr* once.

For example, this result should not be picked up because it belongs to the same *ref1_descr*.

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
|   EMPLID    |  ITEM_TYPE   | ACAD_YEAR | REF1_DESCR |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| 00000010315 | 103201000000 |      2020 |    1938427 |
| 00000010315 | 103201000000 |      2020 |    1938427 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

This should be picked up because the duplicate exists for a unique *ref1_descr*.

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
|   EMPLID    |  ITEM_TYPE   | ACAD_YEAR | REF1_DESCR |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| 00000592537 | 104110123000 |      2020 |    1941668 |
| 00000592537 | 104110123000 |      2020 |    1941164 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

This will pick up both examples, but I need it to ignore the first because the rows share a *ref1_descr*.

```
SELECT emplid, item_type, acad_year, COUNT(*)
FROM ps_item_sf
GROUP BY emplid, item_type, acad_year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**EDIT**

Appologies - I should have included an expected output in my original question.

> I think you want an extra condition in the having clause:
>
> ```
> SELECT emplid, item_type, acad_year, COUNT(*)
> FROM ps_item_sf
> GROUP BY emplid, item_type, acad_year
> HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
>        MIN(REF1_DESCR) <> MAX(REF1_DESCR);
> ```

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
|   EMPLID    |  ITEM_TYPE   | ACAD_YEAR | REF1_DESCR |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| 00000027710 | 104300113000 |      2020 |    1956315 |
| 00000027710 | 104300113000 |      2020 |    1946006 |
| 00000027710 | 104300113000 |      2020 |    1946006 |
| 00000027710 | 104300113000 |      2020 |    1946006 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

And the result:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
|   EMPLID    |  ITEM_TYPE   | ACAD_YEAR | COUNT(*) |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 00000027710 | 104300113000 |      2020 |        4 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

I was expecting it to return a count of 2.

Comment: Changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT REF1_DESCR)` will make it 2, if that is what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using `count()` analytic function with `distinct ref1_descr` partitioning by the remaining three columns :

```
with t as
(
select count(distinct ref1_descr) over (partition by emplid,  item_Type, acad_year) as cnt,
       t.*
  from tab t
)  
select emplid, item_type, acad_year, ref1_descr
  from t
 where cnt > 1
```

in order to return those two rows only

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ddd7860790c326678e64055a2b2a3e37)</kbd>

Comment: Ohh, clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an extra condition in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT emplid, item_type, acad_year, COUNT(*)
FROM ps_item_sf
GROUP BY emplid, item_type, acad_year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
       MIN(REF1_DESCR) <> MAX(REF1_DESCR);
```

Actually, if the descriptions are different, then there are at least two rows, so you can remove the `COUNT(*) condition:

```
HAVING MIN(REF1_DESCR) <> MAX(REF1_DESCR);
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT emplid, item_type, acad_year, COUNT(DISTINCT REF1_DESCR)
FROM ps_item_sf
GROUP BY emplid, item_type, acad_year
HAVING MIN(REF1_DESCR) <> MAX(REF1_DESCR);
```

This seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks. That is close but it is identifying the right group but is not counting correctly. Editing my question with result.

Comment: @waterloomatt . . . Just use `count(distinct REF1_DESCR)` if that is what you want.  It was not clear when I answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it about `DISTINCT`? See line #10:

```
SQL> with test (emplid, item_type, acad_year, ref1_descr) as
  2    (select 27710, 104300113000 , 2020, 1956315 from dual union all
  3     select 27710, 104300113000 , 2020, 1946006 from dual union all
  4     select 27710, 104300113000 , 2020, 1946006 from dual union all
  5     select 27710, 104300113000 , 2020, 1946006 from dual
  6    )
  7  select emplid,
  8         item_Type,
  9         acad_year,
 10         count(distinct ref1_descr) cnt      --> DISTINCT here?
 11  from test
 12  group by emplid, item_type, acad_year
 13  having count(*) > 1
 14    and min(ref1_descr) <> max(ref1_descr);

    EMPLID      ITEM_TYPE  ACAD_YEAR        CNT
---------- -------------- ---------- ----------
     27710   104300113000       2020          2

SQL>
```